# TypeScript Array Sort Not Working as Expected with Optional Property

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of objects in TypeScript based on an optional property ind. If both a and b have the ind property, I want to sort the array in descending order based on ind. Otherwise, if either a or b (or both) lacks the ind property, I want to sort the array in ascending order based on the createdAt property.

Here's my sorting code:

```
const sortedArray = arrayToSort.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.ind && b.ind) {
    return b.ind - a.ind; // Sort by ind in descending order
  } else {
    return (
      new Date(a.createdAt).getTime() -
      new Date(b.createdAt).getTime()
    ); // Sort by createdAt in ascending order
  }
});
```

However, the sorting does not seem to work as expected, and the result is not sorted correctly.

The array elements have the following structure:

```
interface ArrayElement {
  ind?: number;
  createdAt: string;
  // other properties...
}
```

Comment: You have not defined a consistent ordering; consider `const v1 = { ind: 1, createdAt: "2023-07-15" }; const v2 = { ind: 2, createdAt: "2023-07-17" }; const v3 = { createdAt: "2023-07-16" };`.  Your comparator says that `v2 < v1`, and that `v3 < v2` and that `v1 < v3`.  So I don't understand what it would mean for results to be sorted "correctly".  Please [edit] to provide a [mre] of expected input and output, with a description of an actually consistent ordering, and then maybe we can help. Or I could just write up an answer showing the problem with your code. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, this kind of records you listed, is very likely, how can I solve the issue? I would give a priority when records has the `ind` anyway the `createdAt`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what "I would give a priority when records has the `ind` anyway the `createdAt`" means. Could you rephrase?  And again, could you please [edit] to provide a [mre] with sample input/outputs?  That way, instead of relying on verbal descriptions of an ordering, we can compare actual code-based results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `ind` property is optional, Typescript can not guarantee that `a.ind` and `b.ind` are always defined.

As per your current code, You are directly subtract the `ind` values when both `a.ind` and `b.ind` are available. To get rid from typescript error, You can check for `undefined` values.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const arrayToSort = [{
  ind: 1
}, {
  ind: 5
}, {
  ind: 8
}, {
  ind: undefined
}, {
  ind: 7
}, {
  ind: 2
}]

const sortedArray = arrayToSort.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a?.ind !== undefined && b?.ind !== undefined) {
    return b.ind - a.ind;
  } else if (a?.ind !== undefined) {
    return -1; // Move 'a' before 'b'
  } else if (b?.ind !== undefined) {
    return 1; // Move 'b' before 'a'
  } else {
    return
      new Date(a.createdAt).getTime() -
      new Date(b.createdAt).getTime()
  }
});

console.log(sortedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your interface it seems you ind type is number, if ind is 0 it will be considered as false and even if there is ind in that situation that condition wont be satisfied.

Solution is to check for key availability this way.
`

```
if (a.ind !== undefined && b.ind !== undefined) {
    return b.ind - a.ind;
  } else {
    rest of the code....
```

OR

```
if (a.hasOwnProperty('ind') && b.hasOwnProperty('ind')) {
    return b.ind - a.ind;
  } else {
    rest of the code...
```

Comment: there is no `ind` : 0, it starts with 1

Comment: You accepted the same answer what I am trying to explain here.

Comment: no, the trick was this: `if (a?.ind !== undefined) {
    return -1; // Move 'a' before 'b'
  } else if (b?.ind !== undefined) {
    return 1; // Move 'b' before 'a'
  }`